# Thread em python

Tags: python, multithreading

Pra ser bem rápido estou tentando criar 10 threads para que 10 tentativas por vez sejam feitas, ou seja, de 10 em 10 para que o processo seja agilizado economizando tempo e processamento(talvez), meu código inicial é o seguinte:

```
import threading
import requests
import time

url = 'https://www.nitrxgen.net/md5db/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0'}

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, number):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self.number = number
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('Rodando ' + str(self.number))
        with open('/Users/user/Documents/4500md5hashss.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.replace('\n', '')
                s = line.split(';')
                r = requests.get(url + s[0], headers=headers)
                # print r.url
                if r.content == '':
                    print 'Falha'
                else:
                    print(s[1] + '|' + r.content)


thread_list = []
for i in range(10):
    thread = MyThread(i)
    thread_list.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

print('finalizado')
```

O problema eh que desta maneira ele não funciona certo, aparentemente não está criando 10 "instancias", como devo proceder? minha thread está correta?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, neste caso você está instanciando toda vez, recomendo que se for possível, modifique a forma de execução do seu código, para que você de o start na thread por fora dela, abaixo segue um exemplo de um código que uso multiprocessing.
Utilizando os parametros **target** e **args** ou **kwargs**

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class Mprocess:

  @staticmethod
  def excel():  
      try:
            pt = [1,2,3,4]    
            proc = []
            for k in range(len(pt)):
                proc.append(Process(target=clx.convert1, args=(pt[k], from_path, to_path,)))
            for p in proc:
                p.start()
            for p in proc:
                p.join()    
             return 
      except Exception as e:
          'some exception'
```